# Ubuntu 13.04 crash after a while (Black Screen)

Tags: drivers, 13.04, ati, xorg, lock-screen

I have an Inspiron 7520. I got an AMD Radeon HD 7730m 2go with a Intel HD 4000 running on Open Source driver updated from X-edgers repository. I got also a I7 2.4ghz overclocking to 3.1ghz.

The problem I experience today is that when I leave my computer untouched, my screen goes black(as expected) but I can't wake him up. The screen remains black. The thing that tells me that the computer crashes is that my wireless card crashed. I have lost the connection between this computer and another one, transfering data from SSH

Answer (score 0):

SSH will do that in certain circumstances if you have not set the Key Exchange interval to a higher amount/time.  Try to set it higher and let us know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: it does it even if I am not transfering anything.